# Flutter Exception: Could not find open port on host

Tags: flutter

I'm unable to install a Flutter app onto my iPhone from Android Studio (that used to work). When I launch from Android Studio, and the app hangs on a white screen until I see the error message:

```
Exception: Could not find open port on host.
```

When launching from Xcode, the app builds and runs just fine.

The same project runs fine for my coworkers, and even for me, when I launch it on a different computer.

What would cause such behavior?

I've tried `flutter upgrade` and `flutter clean`, but neither fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web for hours, I finally found a solution, a [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93187#issuecomment-973766307) recommending to delete Flutter's `cache/bin` directory followed by a `flutter docter`. I've distilled this down to a two-liner for OSX:

```
rm -rf  $(dirname $(dirname $(which flutter)))/bin/cache/*
flutter doctor
```